# Dispatch a class method

Tags: python

Given the below piece of code how do you correctly dispatch a class method:

```
>>> class A:
...     def a(self):
...         pass
...     def b(self):
...         pass
...     c = a
...     dispatch_map = { 'a' : a, 'b' : b }
...     def dispatch(self, arg):
...         self.dispatch_map[arg]()   # Fail: unbound method!
>>> A().c
<bound method A.a of <__main__.A object at 0x100550210>>
>>> A().dispatch_map['a']
<function a at 0x10054acf8>
```

Why is `c` a bound method, whereas `dispatch_map['a']` is an unbound method.
This is simple with plain functions, and is a common idiom for a select/case replacement, what is the correct way to do this with class methods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only bind a method when there is an instance to bind *to*. Your dispatch map builds the map with just the class instead.

Build the map in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.dispatch_map = { 'a' : self.a, 'b' : self.b }
```

or bind the methods explicitly in your `dispatch()` method:

```
def dispatch(self, arg):
    bound = self.dispatch_map[arg].__get__(self, type(self))
    bound()
```

This uses the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) to bind the method, which is what normally happens when a method is looked up on an instance.

Comment: Thank you, I like the later approach being more memory efficient, especially if you have a large number of instances. Shame it's so unreadable.